# Meaning of equating two curves

Tags: conic-sections

What is the geometrical meaning of equating two curves, in general?

For e.g equating a circle with another gives a line passing through their common points of intersection.
Equating two planes gives their line of intersection.

I understand this can be proved but I don't understand it intuitively. E.g what would I get on equating a circle with a line, or a circle with a parabola etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The “equation of curve” is not directly a statement about the curve.  It is actually an equation that a *point* on the curve needs to satisfy. For example, $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2-25=0$ is a constraint that points $(x,y)$ need to satisfy. $(3,4)$ meets that criterion, whereas $(2,10)$ does not. The set of all points that satisfies this condition is the circle $C$.

Similarly $g(x,y)=2x+3y-1=0$ specifies the set of points that form that line $L$. Now, if a point $p=(a,b)$ is in the intersection of both curves, then it lies in both $C$ and $L$. So it must satisfy both sets of constraints. $f(a,b)=0$ and $g(a,b)=0$. So you can set  $f(a,b)=g(a,b)=0$ and solve it to find all conditions that $p=(a,b)$ must meet. There might be more than one such $p$. The solution gives you the whole set of such $p$ points.

Please note that to find the intersection, you must use the final equality (equating to zero) 
$$f(a,b)=g(a,b)\mathbf{=0}$$

Else, you will get a locus.

For example, if f=0 and g=0 represent the unit circles centered at p=(-1,0) and q=(1,0) respectively and radius of 13 each. Here $f(x,y)=(x+1)^2+y^2-13^2$ and $g(x,y)=(x-1)^2+y^2-13^2$, then think about what $f=g$ means.
Here $f$ and $g$ represent the (square of) distance of a point from the respective centers (offset by a constant). That constant is the square of the radius.

Then if you solve $f=g=0$, then we are asking “what are all the points at a distance **of 13** from both p and q?”  The answer is just two points $(0,\pm 12)$.

But if you just solve $f=g$, we are only asking “what is the set of points equidistant from p and q” and the answer to that of course, is a whole line (the y axis).

Now in this case, $f$ and $g$ had meanings in terms of distances. That may not be the case for all equations of curves. So basically, whenever you equate $f$ and $g$, you need to ask yourselves what $f$ and $g$ mean in the first place and you will find that the your solution is simply turn set of points that satisfies both meanings.

Comment: In that case, equating two circles should give us their points of intersection but it gives us a line passing through it. Why?

Comment: @xasthor No, you get zero, one or two points depending on how the circles meet, never a line. Do you have an example to illustrate what you mean?

Comment: I think I know what you are thinking. Please see edits to that answer.

Comment: What exactly would a point on, say a parabola or other curves represent?

Comment: A parabola is the locus of points equidistant from a given point (focus) and a given line (directrix). http://amsi.org.au/ESA_Senior_Years/SeniorTopic2/2a/2a_2content_10.html hyperbola: given two points a and b and a constant distance (m) the hyperbola is the locus if points p such $|d(p,a)-d(p,b)|=m$ where d(,) is the distance.   http://www.mathwords.com/f/foci_hyperbola.htm You will find it useful to read broadly about loci.

Answer (score 0):

What you call "equating two curves" is actually a statement about the locus of all points $(x,y)$ that satisfy an equation in two variables. This is a special case of what is called a "pencil of curves". For example, suppose $f(x,y)=0,\;g(x,y)=0$ are the equations of two circles in the plane. If $a,b$ are any two reals, not both $0$, then equating the linear combination $\;af(x,y)+bg(x,y)\;$ to $\;0\;$ is the equation of a pencil of circles that pass through the points of intersection of the two original circles. The special case $\;a=1,b=-1\;$ corresponds to your question about two circles. Notice  that if $\;f(x,y),\;g(x,y)\;$ are quadratic polynomials, then any linear combination is also quadratic at most.

Comment: I am afraid that the concept of "pencil of curves" is a little to high for somebody who is visibly a beginner in analytic geometry.